# How do I get link tag to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two files called `list.html.erb` and `register.html.erb`.

I clicked the link

```
<%= link_to 'Lists',posts_list_path %>
```

but I didn't get any response. After clicking the link I expected to go `list.html.erb` page.

routes.rb:

```
resources :posts
post '/posts/list',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'list'
post '/posts/register',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'register'
```

register.html.erb:

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<%= link_to 'Lists',posts_list_path %>
```

---

```
Started GET "/posts/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 00:08:27 +0530 
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"list"} 
Rendered posts/register.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms) 
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) [2014-03-20 00:08:27] 
WARN Could not determine content-length of response body. 
Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: Check your logs. Is the correct action being invoked? Are you seeing any errors? What does your action output? We can't help you unless you give us a llot more information.

Comment: why did u edit your question back??

Comment: i did not got list.html.erb page.i got the same page(register.html.erb)

Comment: can u paste your development logs as well, that will help

Comment: @AshishChopra i forgot to mention the file type

Comment: @AshishChopra i can not paste  my development logs.its said too long characters

Comment: Only paste the server logs generated when you click on the link. You can get it from console where `rails server` is running.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Started GET "/posts/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 00:08:27 +0530
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"list"}
  Rendered posts/register.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-03-20 00:08:27] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Comment: @user3279260 Next time add the logs in the Question not in the comments so they are more readable. Also, see my answer.

Comment: I added the log excerpt to the question for readability.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you.what i can need to add in Posts_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the routes as

```
 get '/posts/list',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'list'
 get '/posts/register',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'register'
 resources :posts
```

When you click on the `<%= link_to 'Lists',posts_list_path %>` link
`link_to` is going to send a GET request as `posts/list`.
That's why you need a GET request here not POST.

Also, the two extra `get` routes should be before `resources :posts` else
Rails would map it to

```
GET    /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#show
```

If you check the logs, you'll notice that the request is going to `PostsController#show`.
Rails would just direct you to the first matching route. Add the  extra `get` routes before `resources :posts` so the routes are mapped correctly.

Comment: Share the server logs generated after you made changes in the `routes.rb` in the question.

Comment: Started GET "/posts/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 00:35:01 +0530
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"list"}
  Rendered posts/register.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 62.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-03-20 00:35:01] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Comment: Did you change the routes as I specified in the answer? Note the order of routes, its important to have them in that order.

Comment: thanks a lot.its working well.thank you for your support.@Kirti Thorat

Comment: Glad to help.Please accept the answer when you get time. :)

Comment: resources :posts                                                           get '/posts/list',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'list'
get '/posts/register',:controller=>'posts',:action=>'register'
resources :posts                                                         i forgot to delete my first line.that's why i am getting same error.i tried more than one day.but i did not get the output.now i got the output.all because of you.once again thank to you.@ Kirti Thorat

Comment: You can thank me by accepting the answer. Check the checkmark under the 0, on my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is make a `POST` request via a `link_to`.  If you actually want to do that the `link_to` should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Lists',posts_list_path,method: :post %>
```